# How to write dax formula for gained customers based on units?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to write a dax formula that establishes the units that a customer bought throughout every year. I want to create formulas that establishes when I select a year in the filter that is the current year and compare that to the previous year. current year units to be defined and prior units to be defined. From there, I am not sure how to write this. The formula should say this... a gained customer is when in the current year they did (what the selected threshold value in filter is selected) or more and in prior year they did less than the selected threshold. I have time as sales(year) sales(customer ID) units (measure) PLS HELP

I have a formula I just dont know if it is correct. It is coming close to the numbers that I want but not exact

Comment: what do you mean by "gained customers"? New customers that you didn't have last year? This year's customers EXCEPT last year's customers. There's an example of new/returning customers on daxpatterns.com

Comment: @Pieter Gained is for the year that is selected in the prior year they did less than the selected threshold in units.  and in the current year they did that amount or more

Comment: If all you're doing is "is this year better than last year" then use CALCULATE() and SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a normal fact table (CustomerKey, DateKey, ProductKey, Quantity), and then a Calendar/Date table that has all the dates from the first date to the last date in your fact table, then this should be pretty easy.

Sales = SUMX('SalesFact',[Quantity] * RELATED([Price]) )

PY Sales = CALCULATE([Sales],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('DimDate'[Date]))

Then the change is [Sales] - [PY Sales]
% Change = DIVIDE([Sales] - [PY Sales],[PY Sales])

Check out the time intelligence patterns on daxpatterns.com